# Использование в цикле if результата итерации itertools.product

Tags: python-3.x

Имеется следующий код:

```
import itertools

t = 0
q = 1
w = ['mark', 'mkra', 'karm']

res = ["".join(var) for var in itertools.product('makr', 
repeat=4)]

word = w[t:q]
if word in res:
print(word)
t+=1
q+=1
```

Это еще не дописанный цикл, но суть такая, создается список из всех комбинаций, далее по другому списку перебираются значения с целью поиска совпадения в res. Res содержит искомое значение, word в момент присваивания также содержит нужное значение, но на if работа приостанавливается, при том, если в word в самом if цикле записать к примеру 'mark', то цикл успешно выполнится. В чем я не прав?

Немного переделал для большей наглядности:

```
import itertools

def my_func():
       t = 0
       q = 1
       w = ['mark', 'mkra', 'karm']
       word = w[t:q]
       if word not in res:
                    print(word)
       else:
                    print('wrong')

res = ["".join(var) for var in itertools.product('makr', 
repeat=4)]
my_func()
```

Если выставить if not in, то ворд выводится, т.е. он просто не может его найти, почему?

Comment: Поправьте отступы.

Comment: Пробовал, все так же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то тут проблемы с типами данных. Вот так должно работать:

```
import itertools

def my_func():
        w = ['mark', 'mkra', 'karxcfm']
        for i in range(len(w)):
            word = w[i]
            if word in res:
                print(word)
            else:
                print('wrong')

res = ["".join(var) for var in itertools.product('makr', 
repeat=4)]
my_func()
```

А перебор в списке W можно в цикле прописать.

Comment: Да, спасибо, это работает